# Proving Multiplicity in Polynomials with derivatives.

Tags: polynomials, induction

After learning multiplicity in polynomials we were given the task of proving that:

**if** $ f(\alpha) = f'(\alpha) = f''(\alpha) = f'''(\alpha) =$ ....   $f^{k-1}(\alpha) = 0$ **and** $f^{k}(\alpha) \not= 0$

then $(x-\alpha)$ is a root of $f(x)$ of multiplicity of $k$.

By logic we know this to be true however when trying to prove it I have experienced great difficulty.

I have so far tried using mathematical induction with little success and by algebraically differentiating it to ultimately show that $ (x-\alpha)^{m-k} = 0 $ where $m$ is the multiplicity of  $ (x-\alpha) $ and therefore must be $k$ but do not feel like this proof is substantial enough as it relies on an *undefined value*.

The starting point for my proof's so far have been with $ f(x) = (x-\alpha)^m * Q(x)$.

I was hoping if someone here could show me a proof for this using one of the above methods or any others (such as contradiction).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not (necessarily) about induction...

$f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ because $f(\alpha)=0$

$f'(x)=(x-\alpha)g'(x)+g(x)$..

As $f'(\alpha)=0$ we have $g(\alpha)=0$ so, $g(x)=(x-\alpha)g_1(x)$ and so $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2g_1(x)$...

Repeat this... Can you continue from here?

Comment: That's a very interesting idea. How would I go about mathematically proving it? (like in a formal method)

Comment: @Monacraft : I do not understand what formal method you are looking for.. This is the most formal method that i am aware of...